# Periodic Code with QT

Tags: c++, qt, callback, serial-port

I'm trying to create a periodic callback using QT.  I'm thinking, something like OpenGL's periodic callback.

Basically, I have a micro controller which is waiting for an event to happen.  When the event Happens it sends the time over the serial port to the PC.  On the PC side, I want the GUI to update whenever this time information is received, or to periodically check to see if there is anything in the Rx buffer.

Is there any built in functionality of Qt to periodically call a methood?

If not is there a way to create a signal between QextSerial, and The GUI?

Or, will I have to make a multi-threaded app with an observer/observable relationship between the serialPort, and the GUI?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html). They also list an example of an [analog clock](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-analogclock.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for when I asked the question.  However, I found another method which I think may be better for my specific application.  I Listed it another answer.

Answer (score 1):

For my specific needs I ended up using a QextSerialPort.

I attached a signal to the Port so that whenever a message was received it would add the time to the Model, and update the GUI.

```
Port = new QextSerialPort();
//... various Port Setup
connect(Port, SIGNAL(readyRead()),      this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
```

This way I was able to keep the Data Model and GUI more separated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using QSocketNotifier.

I've used it to read and process standard input. You just need to change your the file you read from (in my case STDIN_FILENO)

```
---hpp
class QSocketNotifier;
class ConsoleReader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ConsoleReader(QObject *parent = 0);
Q_SIGNALS:
    void textReceived(QString message);
public Q_SLOTS:
    void text();
private:
    QSocketNotifier* notifier;
};

---cpp
#include <QSocketNotifier>
#include <unistd.h> //Provides STDIN_FILENO

ConsoleReader::ConsoleReader(QObject *parent)
 : QObject(parent)
{
    notifier = new QSocketNotifier(STDIN_FILENO, QSocketNotifier::Read);
    connect(notifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(text()));
}

void ConsoleReader::text()
{
    QTextStream qin(stdin);
    QString line = qin.readLine();
    Q_EMIT textReceived(line);
}
```